# Amazon Codebuild error while building : YAML_FILE_ERROR

Tags: docker-compose, meanjs, aws-code-deploy, docker-container, aws-codebuild

Any help with this error:
While running Amazons Codebuild using the meanjs.org stack from the GitHub repo, I am getting an error message in the 'Download Source' phase:
Message: YAML file does not exist

It seems that amazon is requesting a build spec.yml file to complete the build

Any help with finding/creating this file for this repo?

I am using the meanjs.org docker image for the build environ
And the source code is he GitHub repo

Comment: Welcome on SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do not forget to provide some code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and format your question properly, using the [provided markdown options](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

CodeBuild has documentation about creating your buildspec.yaml [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html).

What the buildspec does is executes the commands that you would like to run. For example if I wanted to create a buildspec that installed ruby gems, and then ran a jekyll build my buildspec would look like.

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    key: "value"

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - bundle install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo "******** Building Jekyll site ********"
      - jekyll build
```

Let me know if you have any questions.